# Google JavaScript API - need JavaScript (Angular) application to authenticate as admin account

Tags: javascript, angular, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am attempting to create an angular application that authenticates to the Google APIs as our administrator account so that it can gather details, such as a user's Google Drive info (number of files, total size, etc.)

I'm attempting to use OAuth 2.0 to give the application our "administrator" credentials.  The [examples provided in the Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests) shows how to accomplish such tasks by allowing a user to log themselves in, but I've yet to find anything demonstrating how to programmaticly authenticate an application as admin (or anything else, for that matter).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, I finally found a [question relevant to the issue with what appears to be a detailed solution!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943631/how-can-i-create-google-apps-user-account-programatically)  It's all about using the right key words... "programatically" was the word that finally got me there :)

Of course, I'll be using JavaScript/Angular, not Python, but I believe the concepts will be the same.